# Call a Switch with text Strings multiple times using a Scanner

Tags: java

One of the starting assignments in my Java class is to tell a short story using Scanners to get input from the user to choose a part and go Forward/Back.

The start of my code in the main class looks like this:

```java
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which part of my morning would you like to know about? \"Routine\", \"Commute\", or \"At School\"?");
        String part = sc.next();
    System.out.print(story(part));
```

I tried building a switch in a separate `public static String` class and then return it using `System.out.print(story(part));`. It looks like this:

```java
    public static final String story(String part) {
        switch (part) {

            case "Routine":
                System.out.println("I wake up at...");
                break;
            case "Commute":
                System.out.println("I take the bus...");
                break;
            case "At School":
                System.out.println("I hang out with friends");
                break;
            case "Finish":
                System.out.println("Thank you for reading.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Part title not recognized. Please try again.");
                break;
        }
        return story(part);
```

While the IDE doesn't show any errors, when I run the code, the output is multiple lines of the selected part and then an error message about the `return story(part)` line.

I'm just generally confused on how I should approach this task, and how to recall the results of the switch multiple times with the scanner so that I get no Duplicate errors. I don't need a full answer, but some guidance on how to finish this or what I'm doing wrong would be helpful.

Edit: As suggested by @Jb-Nizet, I replaced the `System.out.println` in the switch with `return` and removed the `return story(part);`, which fixed the recursion problem.

Now my remaining question is can I recall the same switch/class in the main class multiple times using Scanners? Or should I create multiple new classes with switches with cases "Next" or "Previous"?

Comment: Your method calls itself recursively at `return story(part);`. Do you mean to return those Strings instead of printing them inside the switch?

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah, I need to return the Strings, but I'm trying to use the switch to determine which String should be returned.

Comment: System.out.println() displays a string on the screen. That's very different from returning a value to the caller of the method. `return` does that. Replace all the System.out.println() inside story() by `return`. And remove the `return story(part);`

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error then it is a good idea to show it.

I suspect that the error might be a stack overflow error (this site is named after it) because of

`return story(part);`

That call the function `public static final String story(String part)` before it was able to finish. The computer needs to remember to finish it so he puts it on "stack" (memory of the computer) and starts to execute the function again and again needs to put it on the stack and eventually it runs out of memory and throws out an error.

Quick fix: Don't call a function inside of that function. Use a cycle outside of the function like:

```
while(true){   
  story(part); 
}
```

Fun fact: Calling function inside that function is called recursion and it is a quick inefficient way to program. Next time you use it, make sure it doesn't repeat too many times and always have a way to break the cycle of the function calling itself.